# Find statistic values for linear regression

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics

I have a difficulty understand the solution to my coursework, it was explained to me but I still dont understand it so I hope someone please help me?

The question is
A clothes shop manager records the weekly sales figures, £ s, and the average weekly temperature, t °C, for 6 weeks during the summer. The sales figures were coded so that

w = $\dfrac{s}{1000}$

Statistic given are
$S_{ww} = 50$

I need to find value for $S_{ss}$

The solution of this problem is

$1000^2 * S_{ww}$

I got that I can isolate s from code above as $s = 1000w$ and I understand that the equation to find $S_{xx}$ but I dont understand why the solution drop w from 1000w and why do I need $S_{ww}$?

Hope you can explain this to me please
Thank you